# I am trying to check whether the user is an admin or a standard user

Tags: php, html, css, sql

When a user logs in to the site, I want it to run a check on whether or not they are an admin. If they are an admin I would like to send them to the admin page and if they are a user then send them to the homepage. However I am having a few issues. 
The errors that have come up are

> "Syntax Error, unexpected == (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ',' or ')'".

I am trying this using xampp. Admin is the row on the database which would store the `integers` either 1 or 2. 
1 being a standard user and 2 being the admin.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'] == '1' OR $_SESSION['admin'] == '')){
    header('Location: home.php');
} else if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'] === '2')){
    header('Location: admin.php');
}
```

I expect that when a standard user logs in to the website that it should redirect them to the homepage, however when an admin logs in then it should redirect them to the admin page.

Comment: isset — Determine if a variable is declared and is different than NULL, not a condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to check if a condition isset, but [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (in docs) determine if a variable is declared and is different than NULL

You should check like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['admin'] === "2") {
        header('Location: admin.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: home.php');
}
```

Comment: This kind of works, however when the admin is logged into the account. Instead of redirecting to admin.php it redirects to authenticate.php (which is the script that checks if the username and password are correct).

Comment: @JackPartington i think that this is another question. I can't see in question nothing about authenticate.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from **Post Login** file directly by checking rows of the database and giving appropriate **header location**.
See the below code of mine

```
if($rows['registrationType'] == 1) //for user
        {
            $_SESSION['user']['id'] = $rows['userId'];//Set Sessions
            header('location: user/index.php');
        }
        elseif($rows['registrationType'] == 2) // for admin
        {
            $_SESSION['admin']['id'] = $rows['userId'];//Set Sessions

            /*Header Location Redirects to that page*/
            header('location: admin/index.php');

        }
```